# RTNETLINK Error with spi communication

Tags: analog-to-digital, spi

When I use both PICAN-CAN-Bus module and MCP3008 with different cs on spi, I receive this message on terminal;

```
RTNETLINK answers: Device or resource busy
```

I tried to configuration can0 and I received that message.

PICAN : http://skpang.co.uk/catalog/pican-canbus-board-for-raspberry-pi-p-1196.html

MCP3008 : https://www.adafruit.com/datasheets/MCP3008.pdf

Comment: Perhaps you could edit your post and add links to the specs of the modules for those who haven't any idea what they are?  Also details of what you do to cause the message.

Comment: The skpang link contains instructions to use their custom kernel.  Have you followed those instructions and did you get any error messages?

Comment: as far as i am concerned you talk about kernel configuration. I had followed these steps before updated kernel version. Now I'm trying again and i got error message when i write this command:`git fetch --depth=1 git://github.com/raspberrypi/linux.git rpi-3.18.y:refs/remotes/origin/rpi-3.18.y`
and the error message is: `! [rejected]        rpi-3.18.y -> origin/rpi-3.18.y  (non-fast-forward)`